# jQuery.hover() css effect on select field in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, hover

In my project there is a requirement for each `select` field in a form to have a fixed `css` max-width that increases in width on hover to a new, fixed `max-width` and still functions as a normal `select` field should.

CSS:

```
select { max-width: 200px; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").hover( function() {
        $(this).css('max-width','395px');
    }, function() {
        $(this).css('max-width','200px');
    });
});
```

This all works fine as per the requirement except in IE (any version) as the field will increase in width initially but when clicked will immediately open and then close the options that appear.

I believe this is because the `hoverout` function is triggered in IE, the max-width change is triggered and for some reason then believes the select should no longer be in a clicked state.

My question is how can I get this functionality to work in IE too?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tet5m/

Comment: I would like to help you, but my IE can't even open this fiddle.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - jsFiddle's UI no longer works in IE8. You might try the raw fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tet5m/embedded/result/